# Tests using InMemoryDatabase and Identity columns, how to deal?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, testing

*.Net Core 2.2 / EFC 2.2.3 / Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 2.2.0*

Imagine that you have a table called Colors with some predefined data.

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Color> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Colors");
    builder.HasKey(r => r.Id).UseMySqlIdentityColumn();
    builder.Property(r => r.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
    builder.Property(v => v.RGB).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(7);
    builder.HasData(GetSeed());
}
private ICollection<Color> GetSeed()
{
    return new List<Color>()
    {
        new Color(){Id=1, Name="Black", RGB="#000"},
        new Color(){Id=2, Name="White", RGB="#fff"},
    }
}
```

One of my tests is to test the CreateColorCommandHandler. Very straightfoward

```cs
var Context = CBERPContextFactory.Create();
var query = new CreateColorCommandHandler(Context);

var command = new CreateColorCommand();
command.Name= "Random color";
command.RGB = "#001122";

var colorId = await query.Handle(command, CancellationToken.None);

//Assert
Assert.IsInstanceOf<long>(colorId);
Assert.NotZero(colorId);

var cor = Context.Colors.Where(p => p.Id == colorId).SingleOrDefault();
Assert.NotNull(cor);
Assert.AreEqual(command.Name, cor.Name);
Assert.AreEqual(command.RGB, cor.RGB);

CBERPContextFactory.Destroy(Context);

//>>> Handle simply add a new entity without informing ID
```

Handle method

```cs
public async Task<long> Handle(CreateColorCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = new Color
    {
        Name = request.Name,
        RGB = request.RGB,
    };

    _context.Colors.Add(entity);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return entity.Id;
}
```

When I ran this test I get the error `An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1`. Which means that InMemoryDatabase do not has auto increment feature.

Am I writing the test wrong?

How can I test case like this? I want to make sure that the command is OK.

Probably I am missing some very basic rule here.

Comment: Can you show `Handle` method? How you are saving new color to the database?

Comment: Notice that `CBERPContextFactory.Destroy(Context);` will not be executed if one of the assertions fails.

Comment: @Fabio, edited to show Handle

Answer (score 0):

I assume problem is in the following line:

```
var Context = CBERPContextFactory.Create();
```

May be you are using the same context instance for multiple tests. According to [Testing with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests) documentation:

> Each test method specifies a unique database name, meaning each method has its own InMemory database.

So make sure that your each and every test  method has a distinct context instance.

**If still does not work then try setting the identity key value manually because InMemory database may does not support auto-increment.**

Comment: Yes I am sure that the name is unique. For every `Create()` call I generate a new GUID and set it as the name: `builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());`

Comment: Try setting the identity key manually because InMemory may ne does not support auto increment. Please let me know the result.

Comment: Yes this works, but isn't wrong doing that? Let me ask something else: do the test database can have seeds?

Comment: In that example I have Colors with Id 1 and 2 already on the database right? If I added other migration with other pre defined Color my test will break but it should not. Am I right?

Comment: @lcssanches 1) `Let me ask something else: do the test database can have seeds?`- Yes should have! 2) Yes it will

Comment: What about this: In that example I have Colors with Id 1 and 2 already on the database right? If I added other migration with other pre defined Color my test will break but it should not. Am I right?

Comment: @lcssanches Yes! You are correct! It will break if the database context is same.

Comment: Using manually Id values does not help, because it is inside the CommandHandle.

Comment: @lcssanches `var command = new CreateColorCommand();command.Id = 1;
command.Name= "Random color";
command.RGB = "#001122";` is not it?

Answer (score 0):

InMemoryDatabase do not have all features yet, and AUTO INCREMENT one of those that need improvements: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6872

**Not the answer I wanted**, but is the one working for now: clear all seeds before testing.

```
    private static void Clear(this DbContext context)
    {
        var properties = context.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var setType = property.PropertyType;
            bool isDbSet = setType.IsGenericType && (typeof(DbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(setType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()));
            if (!isDbSet) continue;
            dynamic dbSet = property.GetValue(context, null);
            dbSet.RemoveRange(dbSet);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```